# calendar in android for java how can fix null

Tags: java, android, null, calendar

1 - here code is :

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(orderTime));
    String formatedDate = DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy",calendar).toString();
    holder.orderDateTv.setText(formatedDate);
```

2 - here error is :

```
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(orderTime));
```

Comment: my guess: orderTime hasn't been instantiated. validate it before trying to parse it.

Comment: share your logcat where is the error